# timeout ie.close not working and time out error occurs

Tags: ruby, watir

```
ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").click

 rescue Timeout::Error
      #sleep(5)

            puts "timeout"
            ie.close

        #sleep(9)

        retry #open new browser and go to begin
            end`
```

**when  .click link gets time out , then output is = timeout, but ie.close does not work.
and the time out error comes**
**i want to close the browser when time out error comes**

Comment: "*i want to close the browser when time out error comes*" you what? Like, the browser that someone is on? _why_?

Comment: i want a infinite loop if timeout occur.until i got desire output.after time out,
browser should be close, and then again new browser should open.
and this process should repeat until desire output.

Comment: i have edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? what are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us more about what you are doing, there may be a better way to get what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that `ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").click` will ever throw a `Timeout::Error`. This would be why the `rescue` block is never executed.

The likely exceptions that are thrown are:

- When you do `ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").click` and the element is not found, a `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException` will occur.
- When you do `ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").when_present.click` and the element is not found within the required time frame, a `Watir::Wait::TimeoutError` will occur.

Your rescue likely needs to be catching one of these exceptions instead.

```
begin
  ie = Watir::Browser.new
  ie.goto 'www.yourpage.com'
  ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").click
rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException
  puts "element not found"
  ie.close
  retry #open new browser and go to begin
end
```

Or if you are using `when_present` on the element:

```
begin
  ie = Watir::Browser.new
  ie.goto 'www.yourpage.com'
  ie.link(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch").when_presentclick
rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError
  puts "element did not appear in time"
  ie.close
  retry #open new browser and go to begin
end
```